# C# xml file sorting tags by id, but saving same name order

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

Im Trying to sort xml tags by id only between same name tags, I want to make same thing in their children. Right now I can sort only 1st level of the root. Any ideas how to make it in more efficient way?

Thanks for any advice.

**Example before:**

```
<AFDatabase>
        <Element1><id>1</id></Element1>
        <Element1><id>10</id></Element1>
        <Element1><id>5</id></Element1>
        <Element1><id>4</id>
    <ElementInside><id>3</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside><id>2</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside><id>1</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside><id>0</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside4><id>3</id><ElementInside4>
    <ElementInside4><id>2</id><ElementInside4>
    <ElementInside4><id>1</id><ElementInside4>
    <ElementInside2><id>3</id><ElementInside2>
    <ElementInside2><id>2</id><ElementInside2>
    <ElementInside2><id>1</id><ElementInside2>
    </Element1>
```

**///AFTER///**

```
<AFDatabase>
    <Element1><id>1</id></Element1>
    <Element1><id>4</id>

    <ElementInside><id>0</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside><id>1</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside><id>2</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside><id>3</id><ElementInside>
    <ElementInside4><id>1</id><ElementInside4>
    <ElementInside4><id>2</id><ElementInside4>
    <ElementInside4><id>3</id><ElementInside4>
    <ElementInside2><id>1</id><ElementInside2>
    <ElementInside2><id>2</id><ElementInside2>
    <ElementInside2><id>3</id><ElementInside2>

    </Element1>
    <Element1><id>5</id></Element1>
    <Element1><id>10</id></Element1>

</AFDatabase>
```

**Code**

```
 private static XElement xmlSorting(XElement root)
            {

                var xmlStruct = sortRootBYID(root);



                return new XElement(root.Name,
                        root.Attributes(), new XElement("AFDatabase",

                        from child in root.Nodes()
                        where child.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element
                        select child,

                        from child in xmlStruct.Elements()
                        select child));


            }

            private static XElement sortRootBYID(XElement root)
            {
               var ElementNames =  getElementNames(root);


                var xmlStruct = new XElement("x");
                xmlStruct.RemoveAll();
                foreach (var elementName in ElementNames)
                {

                    var orderedTags = root.Elements("AFDatabase").Elements(elementName)
                                           .OrderBy(xtab => (string)xtab.Element("id"))
                                           .ToArray();

                    foreach (XElement tag in orderedTags)
                        xmlStruct.Add(tag);


                }

                return xmlStruct;


            }

            private static HashSet<string> getElementNames (XElement root)
            {
                HashSet<string> ElementNames = new HashSet<string>();
                foreach (var element in root.Elements().Elements())
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine();


                    if (element.Name != null)
                    {
                        ElementNames.Add(element.Name.ToString());
                    }
                }



                return ElementNames;
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be as the following. You would need to sort the First Level elements first, before grouping the inner elements based on Element Name, and then sorting them.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elementCollection = xDoc.Root.Elements("Element1")
                          .OrderBy(x=> int.Parse(x.Element("id").Value)).ToList();

foreach(var element in elementCollection.Where(x=>x.Descendants().Any(c=>c.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("ElementInside"))).ToArray())
{
    var innerElements = element.Descendants()
                         .Where(x=>!x.Name.LocalName.Equals("id"))
                         .GroupBy(x=>x.Name.LocalName)
                         .Select(x=>x.ToList().OrderBy(c=>c.Element("id") == null ? "0" : c.Element("id").Value))
                         .SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
    innerElements.Insert(0,element.Element("id"));
    element.ReplaceAll(innerElements);
}
var result = new XElement("AFDatabase", elementCollection);
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLQeg5)